# How to install multiple odoo 10 instances with subdomain filtering on CentOs

Tags: odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-10

I have been stuck with installing mutiple odoo 10n instances on a server with subdomain filtering, for example:

- xxxx.mydomain.com: an odoo instance installed at /opt/xxxx/
- yyyy.mydomain.com: an odoo instance installed at /opt/yyyy/

To be more specific, I already have an instance of odoo 8 running at opt/odoo/ on odoo.mydomain.com. Now I want to install an instance of odoo 10, with the idea as explained above. Already found a tutorial at https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-odoo-10-with-subdomain-filtering/ but it's for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Run odoo 10 in different port and that's all.

And don't forget to make db filters

Comment: Could you show a detailed tutorial? because I'm new to this

Comment: I can't give you our configuration copy for security reasons. But I already told you everything you need to know. 
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/deploy.html